# Gradle Warning: missing groovy return statement

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm having the following warning in my gradle build file

> Not all execution paths return a value
>
> This inspection reports on missing groovy return statement at the end of methods returning

and this is the code in that file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ac.company.srikar.quickhelpindia"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        android {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell what is the issue here and how to get rid of this warning.

Comment: What's the actual output from gradle? How are you running it?

Comment: I haven't configured debug build type, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @tim_yates I'm not running it. When I opened the module build.gradle file, it is showing the yellow warning message near the scroll bar. In addition to that, when I hover over "release", "minifyEnabled", "proguardFiles", "getDefaultProguardFile" or "compile", it is showing a message that says "cannot resolve the symbol"

Comment: I get this same warning.

Answer (score 50):

With Android Studio 2.2 I had to add a `return void` before the final bracket in the `android` section.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        standard {
            applicationId "com.example.app.standard"
        }

        free {
            applicationId "com.example.app.free"
        }
    }

    // `return void` removes the lint error: `Not all execution paths return a value`.
    return void
}
```

Comment: it would only fix the error for me by adding `return void` to the end of the **defaultConfig** block.

Comment: Andrew, what does your `defaultConfig` look like?

Comment: ```defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 22
        return void // removes the lint error: 'Not all execution paths return a value'
    }```

Comment: Andrew, `applicationID` and either `versionCode` or `versionName` must be defined in either `defaultConfig` or in another section like `productFlavors`.  If they are not defined, you will receive the `lint` error, which can be overridden with `return void` if desired.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info. I posted the `defaultConfig` for our base library that ends up getting compiled into other apps which then sets the `applicationId`. Do libraries need these values set? Also, `versionCode` and `versionName` are currently being set in the `AndroidManifest.xml file`. Can these values be removed if they are set in the gradle file instead?

Comment: `applicationId` only needs to be set once in the place where it makes the most sense, although with some configurations lint may not be able to figure out what you are doing, so you may need to use `return void` to remove an incorrect lint error.

When Android was first released, `versionCode` and `versionName` were specified in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but Google now recommends they be moved to the Gradle build file.  https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Comment: I don't like this solution. It's like fixing a bug by introducing another bug. The correct answer is the link to the bug report: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41353139/2947592

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in Android Studio 2.2, which was fixed in Android Studio 2.3.  `return void` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 16):

I have been getting this same warning and I think it is incorrect. I have read through the gradle documentation and it does not appear that a return type is needed. However, the warnings bug me and the only way I could get rid of it was to add `return true`.

```
buildTypes {
    android {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

I doubt this is the "correct" solution; however, it does remove the warnings and it doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Thanks for this, agreed that I'd rather have a *correct* solution, but I'm glad to be rid of the warnings anyway.

Comment: Good, but I prefer `return null` since the absense of the return statement means I'm returning nothing anyways.

Comment: Or `return void` since this really is meaningless.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this by adding the recommended suppression string from inspection:

```
//noinspection GroovyMissingReturnStatement
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
...
```

Answer (score 9):

I got rid of this warning when I specified both, `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources`.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it and that does not work. I can't see why that would work.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this is an issue fixed in Android Studio 2.3:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223575